# Use my own domain name to access Amazon S3 objects

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a storage for public images in the S3 bucket. Anyone can get the public link to an image from my website, and use it on their own websites. The thing is that the link looks like this:

```
https://my-bucket-name.production.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/images/samplename.png
```

It's bad because every time I change the name of the bucket, or AWS region, the link will no longer be valid. It's also exposing many things to the user and it just looks ugly.

The ideal situation would be to redirect into s3 public link after accessing this:

```
https://example.com/awsstatic/images/samplename.png
```

So the server checks if there is `awsstatic` in the URL, and redirects to the S3 resource to show the image.

Now I could see writing a REST endpoint for that, with the file download, but then each time someone will try to access the image, my server will need to buffer the whole image. It will also get unnecessary additional traffic.

What's the proper process for doing this?

Comment: How about cloudfront?

Comment: Yeah, looks like that's the best option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Route::get('/awsstatic/images/{image}', function($image){
     $url = 'https://my-bucket-name.production.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/images/' . $image;
     return Redirect::away($url)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CloudFront and an alternate domain name. You can also take advantage of edge location caching if you use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Configure a static website using a custom Domain registered with Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).

This will give you a URL like:

```
http://images.example.com/samplename.png
```

Please note that the bucket name will need to match the URL and it will not work for `HTTPS`.